# Things being destroyed on private server when no one is logged in

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

So I have a private server that I rent and run Minecraft on. Me and two others have access to it only. On two occasions I have logged on to find that some things have been destroyed.

First time I found that several chests had been destroyed and most of my items were scattered on the floor. Today I found that a stair had been destoyed, just as if a creeper had exploded there. And inside my house there had been a few, just two or three, blocks that had been mined away (which caused a huge leak in my inside swimmingpool....)

I'm sure none of the others had anything to do with this, so I'm wondering if the mobs are playing around in my house and messing with my stuff when I'm not around?

Comment: Unfortunately, these kind of things often happen. There are few possibilities that would explain your issue. Either one of the two other guys logged in and vandalized your server, or someone stole your username to connect. In this last case, even a white list cannot block this (did you know that some cracks allow users to connect with any username they want). If you had edited your `server.properties` file, check if `online-mode` is set to `true`. If your stuff is still destroyed, don't try to block IP: block every IP and only allow your friends' IPs and yours too. That's it.

Comment: Have you ruled out Enderman griefing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would set up whitelisting on the server if you haven't.

In server.properties set

> white-list=true

and place each of your friend's usernames in white-list.txt to allow them access.

Don't assume no one can connect to your server just because you haven't advertised your IP.

Comment: Turns out I hadn't activated the white list, this must be the reason. Although it still seems weird I haven't had more issues, it seems like someone logged on and just got hit by a creeper and then logged off.
Anyway, whitelist enabled now. I'll see if I run into more problems.

Comment: Yeah I second whitelisting. I now have it active on all my servers even if they are private.

Answer (score 0):

If you notice that things are still getting destroyed, then one of the guys that could connect must be getting hacked or someone is cracked, depending if `online-mode` is true, I once was hacked and had my own nickname changed to a bad word.